# Show that $a_n:=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, cauchy-sequences

Show that $a_n:=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}$ converges.

If $(a_n)$ converges, the sequences is a Cauchy sequence. Which means:

$\forall \epsilon >0 \,\,\,\exists N \in \mathbb{N}\,\,\,m,n>N:\left|\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}-\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{2m-1}\right|<\epsilon$

$\left|\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}-\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{2m-1}\right|\le\left|\frac{1}{2n-1}\right|+\left|\frac{1}{2m-1}\right|<\left|\frac{1}{2N-1}\right|+\left|\frac{1}{2N-1}\right|=\frac{2}{2N-1}<\epsilon\Longleftrightarrow N>\frac{2+\epsilon}{2\epsilon}$

So we choose $N:=\left\lceil \frac{2+\epsilon}{2\epsilon}\right\rceil$

Which means we will always find a $N$ for any $\epsilon>0$

Is this correct?

Comment: You mix-up the convergence of a *sequence* and a *series.*

Comment: Ohh sorry.. i meant this sequence..

Comment: Then it looks correct – but it would be even easier to show directly that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$.

Comment: You also should argue the other way around: If it is a Cauchy sequence then it is convergent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is indeed valid.

Rather than use the Cauchy condition, you could also prove that it converges to $0$ directly: for any $\varepsilon>0$, $|a_n|$ is less than $\varepsilon$ for all $n>\frac 12 \left(1 + \frac 1 \varepsilon\right)$.